# How to know what properties are available of a radio button in visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I read the code from my teacher to make a radiobutton in VS++2010

```
        this->rbSenior->AutoSize = true;
        this->rbSenior->Location = System::Drawing::Point(56, 161);
        this->rbSenior->Name = L"rbSenior";
        this->rbSenior->Size = System::Drawing::Size(55, 17);
        this->rbSenior->TabIndex = 9;
        this->rbSenior->TabStop = true;
        this->rbSenior->Text = L"Senior";
        this->rbSenior->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
and
        if (rbFreshman->Checked) answer = 0;
```

I understand the code, because it is simple. However, how I know whether 'CHECKED' is an available property in radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

1) Read the documentation. Microsof doc are freely available online at [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com). From there a search for "radio button" yield [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx). Alternatively pressing F1 should bring the help if you have installed it.

2) Switch to the "design" view of your form (shift + F7), click on the radio button. There should be a "property" window or toolbox listing the design properties.

3) Use intellisense. Type `this->rbSenior->` then press "ctrl + space". It should list the properties and methods available on any object (doesn't work on most complex cases, but you are not there yet)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MFC and that you have the class variable `mybutton` of (sub)type `CButton`, you can call `mybutton.GetCheck()`, which will return `BST_CHECKED`, `BST_UNCHECKED`, or `BST_INTERMEDIATE`, if applicable.  For a list of members for a certain control, either read the manual (msdn.microsoft.com) or use Visual Studio's intellisense...preferably the former.

Comment: `System::Drawing::Size` doesn't really sound like MFC ;)

Comment: @J.N. - Ah, got a little over-eager there, thanks for pointing that out.  Maybe I should downvote myself! :p